# ng-click not working on button (angularjs-django)

Tags: angularjs, django

I am new to angularjs and unable to figure out why ng-click on a button is not working. I am pasting code below. I am using a django server to render the page.

HTML CODE:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">

<div class="container-fluid" >
    <table class="col-xs-12-ls-12 mfPortfolioTable" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
                <td class="search_table_cell col-xs-1-ls-1">{% verbatim %}{{ x.units | number:3 }}{% endverbatim %}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>                
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateMfPortfolio()" id="updateFolio">Update</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('searchApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/somelink/').then(function(response){
      $scope.records = response.data.data;
  });

  //This is the function which I expect to get triggered by ng-click

  $scope.updateMfPortfolio = function(){
      console.log('Updating MF Portfolio...');
      $http.get('/somelink/').then(function(response){
          console.log('Code reached here...');
          $scope.records = response.data.data;
      });
  };
```

Comment: what value of `button` do you see when you see page source (ctrl + U) of that template ? Also, put some alert/console in the `myController` and confirm if it is getting called ? 

Also, I hope you are just using Django template as landing page `index.html` just once and then `angularJS` SPA comes into action. Is it ?

Comment: I figured out the solution. I was missing type="button" in my html button code